# Testes unitários em um upload de arquivos CSV

Tags: java, junit

Antes de explicar o meu problema vou mostrar meu código de upload de arquivos CSV.

```
public String uploadArquivo() {

        try {

            removeInSession(LISTA_TIPO_INDICIOS);
            removeInSession(LISTA_INDICIOS);
            removeInSession(LISTA_ERRO);

            final File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());
            final LineNumberReader linhaLeitura =
                    new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
            linhaLeitura.skip(arquivoLeitura.length());
            final int qtdLinha = linhaLeitura.getLineNumber() + 1;

            final BufferedReader leitor = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(getArquivo())));

            String linha = null;

            leitor.readLine();

            for (int indiceIndicio = 2; indiceIndicio <= qtdLinha; indiceIndicio++) {
                statusMatricula = false;
                linha = leitor.readLine();

                if (linha == null) {
                    break;
                }

                final String[] dadosCSV = linha.split(VIRGULA);
                final int numberPositions = dadosCSV.length;

                setNumberPositions(numberPositions);
                if (!dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO].isEmpty()) {
                    tipoIndicio = new TipoIndicioEntity();
                    tipoIndicio.setCodigo(
                            Integer.parseInt(dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO]));
                    tipoIndicio = tipoDeIndicioService
                            .getPorId(tipoIndicio.getCodigo());
                }
                if (!dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ].isEmpty()) {
                    uJ = new PessoaJuridicaPublicaEntity();
                    uJ.setCodigo(Long.parseLong(dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ]));
                    uJ = pessoaJuridicaPublicaService.pesquisarPorId(uJ);
                }
                final ValidaCPF validadorCPF = new ValidaCPF();

                final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^-?\\d*\\,\\d{2}$");
                final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dadosCSV[VALOR]);

                if (!dadosCSV[NATUREZA].isEmpty()) {

                    naturezaIndicio
                            .setCodigo(Integer.parseInt(dadosCSV[NATUREZA]));
                    naturezaIndicio = naturezaIndicioService
                            .getPorId(naturezaIndicio.getCodigo());
                }
                if (!dadosCSV[CODIGO_DO_VINCULO].isEmpty()) {
                    tipoVinculo = new TipoVinculoEntity();
                    tipoVinculo.setCodigo(
                            Integer.parseInt(dadosCSV[CODIGO_DO_VINCULO]));
                    tipoVinculo = tipoVinculoService
                            .getPorId(tipoVinculo.getCodigo());
                }

                if (getNumberPositions() >= MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO) {
                    if (!dadosCSV[MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO].isEmpty()) {
                        usuarioCorporativo = new UsuarioCorporativoEntity();
                        usuarioCorporativo.setCodigoUsuario(Integer
                                .parseInt(dadosCSV[MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO]));
                        usuarioCorporativo = usuarioCorporativoService.getPorId(
                                usuarioCorporativo.getCodigoUsuario());
                    }
                }

                final boolean expressaoInvalida = matcher.find() == false;
                final boolean cpfInvalido = !validadorCPF.isCPF(dadosCSV[CPF]);
                final boolean descricaoVazia = dadosCSV[DESCRICAO].isEmpty();
                final boolean naturezaInvalida = naturezaIndicio == null;
                boolean dataValidaEncontrada = false;

                if (!dadosCSV[DATA_ADMISSAO].equals("")) {

                    final SimpleDateFormat format =
                            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

                    format.setLenient(false);
                    try {

                        if (dadosCSV[DATA_ADMISSAO] != null
                                && !dadosCSV[DATA_ADMISSAO].isEmpty()) {
                            final Date dataAdmissao =
                                    format.parse(dadosCSV[DATA_ADMISSAO]);
                        }

                    } catch (final Exception e) {
                        dataValidaEncontrada = true;
                    }

                }
                final int qtdData = dadosCSV[DATA_ADMISSAO].length();
                if (qtdData != 10) {
                    dataValidaEncontrada = true;
                }
                qtdMatriculo = dadosCSV[MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO].length();

                final char letra_anterior =
                        dadosCSV[MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO].charAt(0);
                final int vezes = 1;
                int qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario = 0;
                for (qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario =
                        1; qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario < qtdMatriculo; qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario++) {
                    final char letra_atual = dadosCSV[MATRICULA_PROPRIETARIO]
                            .charAt(qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario);

                }

                if (qtdCaracterMatriculaProprietario != 4) {
                    statusMatricula = true;
                }

                if (getNumberPositions() <= 6) {
                    if (tipoIndicio == null
                            || dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO].isEmpty() || uJ == null
                            || dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ].isEmpty() || cpfInvalido
                            || descricaoVazia || expressaoInvalida
                            || naturezaIndicio == null) {
                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros6Linhas(dadosCSV,
                                tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList,
                                indiceIndicio);
                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio,
                                listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);
                    }
                } else if (getNumberPositions() > 6
                        && getNumberPositions() < 13) {
                    if (tipoIndicio == null
                            || dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO].isEmpty() || uJ == null
                            || dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ].isEmpty() || cpfInvalido
                            || dadosCSV[DESCRICAO].isEmpty()
                            || dadosCSV[DESCRICAO] == null || expressaoInvalida
                            || descricaoVazia || naturezaIndicio == null
                            || tipoVinculo == null || usuarioCorporativo == null
                            || statusMatricula) {

                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros12Linhas(dadosCSV,
                                tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList,
                                indiceIndicio, dataValidaEncontrada,
                                tipoVinculo, usuarioCorporativo);
                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio,
                                listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);
                    }
                } else if (getNumberPositions() >= 13) {

                    if (tipoIndicio == null
                            || dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO].isEmpty() || uJ == null
                            || dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ].isEmpty() || cpfInvalido
                            || dadosCSV[DESCRICAO].isEmpty()
                            || dadosCSV[DESCRICAO] == null || descricaoVazia
                            || expressaoInvalida || naturezaIndicio == null
                            || dadosCSV[NATUREZA].isEmpty()
                            || dataValidaEncontrada || tipoVinculo == null
                            || usuarioCorporativo == null || statusMatricula) {

                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros12Linhas(dadosCSV,
                                tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList,
                                indiceIndicio, dataValidaEncontrada,
                                tipoVinculo, usuarioCorporativo);

                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio,
                                listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);

                    }

                }

            }

            leitor.close();

        } catch (

        final FileNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final NegocioException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final PrincipalException e) {
            logger.error(e);
            erroInterno();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return PAGE_IMPORTAR;
    }
```

Quando o usuário seleciona o arquivo CSV e clica para enviar, esse método é acionado, esse código logo acima está funcionando perfeitamente. O que preciso é criar um teste unitário para esse método. O objetivo do teste unitário e testar essas validações abaixo;

```
if (getNumberPositions() <= 6) {
                    if (tipoIndicio == null
                            || dadosCSV[TIPO_DO_INDICIO].isEmpty() || uJ == null
                            || dadosCSV[CODIGO_UJ].isEmpty() || cpfInvalido
                            || descricaoVazia || expressaoInvalida
                            || naturezaIndicio == null) {
                        erroCSVList = ErroCSV.verificarErros6Linhas(dadosCSV,
                                tipoIndicio, uJ, naturezaIndicio,
                                expressaoInvalida, validadorCPF, erroCSVList,
                                indiceIndicio);
                        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, erroCSVList);

                    } else {
                        verificarListaIndicios(listaTotalIndicio,
                                listaIndicioEntity, uJ, tipoIndicio, dadosCSV);
                    }
```

**Agora vou explicar minha dificuldade;**

Quando se faz teste unitários é necessário criar registros falsos para executar simulação dos recursos de uma aplicação.

Mas invés de criar registros falsos eu gostaria de usar os dados do próprio arquivo CSV no ato de executar os teste para o upload do arquivo CSV.

A forma de como o sistema iria se comporta seria que, no momento que o usuário fosse fazer upload do método **uploadArquivo** fosse acionado o teste seria acionado também ao mesmo tempo utilizando dados do próprio arquivo CSV.

Por falta de experiência em testes unitários estou tendo dificuldade de implementar.
Os mesmo dados que estão sendo usados no arquivo CSV e conseguir pegar esses registros na minha classe de testes, eu só preciso de ajuda para pegar registros como por exemplo o arquivoLeitura!

O que vem no meu getArquivo()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que o método "getArquivo()" faz? Só para entender como é o ponto de entrada do arquivo do seu código.

Comment: testes de unidade no geral avaliam uma saída esperada, não um bloco do código, seu problema na verdade é que seu upload de arquivos está todo acoplado as suas validações, primeiramente você precisa separar isso daí

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, é preciso ler o arquivo CSV a partir do teste unitário.

Uma boa prática é deixar estes arquivos de teste no diretório resources dos testes:

```
/src/test/resources/
```

Melhor ainda é criar um diretório próprio para os CSVs:

```
/src/test/resources/csvs/
```

Agora é preciso ler os arquivos dentro deste diretório. Esta classe utilitário quebrará o seu galho:

```
public class LerCsvFile {

    public File getFile(String nomeArquivo) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL resource = classLoader.getResource("csvs/" + nomeArquivo);
        return new File(resource.getPath());
    }

}
```

E para usar no seu teste unitário:

```
File csvFile = new LerCsvFile().getFile("meu_csv.csv");
```

Agora, para usar isto no seu código, parece que você precisa melhorar um pouco a organização dele. A primeira coisa é quebrar em mais classes este código todo. No mínimo, você poderia criar uma classe separada que recebe o arquivo. Assim, você pode testar unitariamente com diferentes arquivos de forma muito mais fácil.

Exemplo:

```
public String uploadArquivo() {

    try {

        removeInSession(LISTA_TIPO_INDICIOS);
        removeInSession(LISTA_INDICIOS);
        removeInSession(LISTA_ERRO);

        final File arquivoLeitura = new File(getArquivo());

        LeituraCsvResultado leituraCSvResultado = new LeituraCsv(arquivoLeitura).ler();

        // depois preencher a session com os dados de LeituraCsvResultado 
        addInSession(LISTA_ERRO, leituraCSvResultado.getErroCSVList()); //algo assim
```

O código que começa em `final LineNumberReader linhaLeitura...` e vai até `leitor.close();` ficaria nesta nova classe `LeituraCsv`. Algo assim:

```
class LeituraCsv {

        private File arquivoLeitura;

        LeituraCsv(File arquivoLeitura) {
            this.arquivoLeitura = arquivoLeitura;
        }

        public LeituraCsvResultado ler() {
            final LineNumberReader linhaLeitura =
                    new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(arquivoLeitura));
            // restante do código

            // preencher LeituraCsvResultado com as listas que vão na sua sessions
            return new LeituraCsvResultado(); 
        }

}
```

Desta maneira, você pode testar unitariamente LeituraCsvResultado com diferentes arquivos e analisando o retorno do LeituraCsvResultado, fazendo os asserts necessários. Exemplo:

```
class LeituraCsvResultadoTest {

    public void ler() {
        File arquivo = new LerCsvFile().getFile("meu_csv.csv");
        LeituraCsvResultado resultado = new LeituraCsv(arquivo).ler(); 
        // fazer os asserts em LeituraCsvResultado 
    }

}
```

Dica: você terá testes e códigos ainda melhores se quebrar a lógica toda em mais classes ainda, pois parece que o seu código pode ser melhorado seguindo este caminho.

Comment: Mano do céu, sensacional, só em olhar para a sugestão já sinto que vai funcionar, eu precisarei de um tempo para testa sua gestão para ver se vai funcionar. dando certo eu já colorarei como resolvido. muito obrigado.

Comment: @Dherick observando com mais calma, estou com um pouco de dificuldade para entender se a sua sugestão é tudo na classe de teste ou parte dela é na classe onde está implementando o método  uploadArquivo, minha outra dificuldade é conseguir navegar pela forma correta para encontrar o arquivo csv utilizando na pasta.

Eu não encontreo método LeituraCsvResultado  implementado na sua sugestão, só peço que tenha um pouco de paciência comigo.

Comment: @wladyband, editei a resposta para deixar mais claro, tinha uns erros mesmo. A classe LeituraCsv é uma classe normal, onde ela recebe o arquivo no construtor e faz a leitura, você precisa criar ela. Parte do código existente seu precisa ser movido para dentro dela. Ela retornará através do método "ler" o resultado, que usará para preencher a session. O teste é basicamente aquilo que coloquei mesmo mais os asserts que você pode fazer para verificar o resultado esperado

Comment: Muito obrigado @Dhreck, sem exagero, mas você irá participar na minha formação como programador, agora ficou mais claro para mim, vou me esforça para funcionar, valeu mesmo.

Comment: @wladyband vou aguardar me citar nos agradecimentos do TCC. Brincadeira :). Fico feliz em ter ajudado, abraço